# Conditionally filtering dependency-injected async data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, dependency-injection

I have a NodeJS application which I've built around dependency injection. The app can run any combination of its functions (modules) at the same time, and any modules that request data from the same async resource will instead share a single request. So if module A and module B both need data from `https://example.com/path/to/resource` and I run both, then that request gets made once and the result is handed off to both modules. Great.

But what if module C only wants *part* of the data from the same resource? If I run modules A-C, then it can just await the data and filter the result, but that's wasteful when I only want to run module C. Conversely, if I just have module C request path + `?filter=foo`, then that's efficient when only module C is run, but wasteful if A-C are as two requests would be made for a superset of the same data.

I *sort of* see a way to create an optimizing technique around this, but I'm somewhat new to dependency injection and I'm afraid I'll end up creating an anti-pattern or something convoluted and hard to maintain. What's the best approach to handling this?

## EDIT

To clarify, in an ideal solution, that example would only have three possible flows and request one of two possible URLs depending on the set of modules being run:

1. Set = {A}, {B}, or {A, B}. We request `/path/to/resource` and pass the result as is to the modules.
2. Set = {C}. We request `/path/to/resource?filter=foo` and pass the result as is to the module.
3. Set = {C, A}, {C, B}, or {C, A, B}. We request `/path/to/resource`. To modules A/B, we pass the result as is. But to module C, we first process the result for foo before passing it along.

This way, **C never needs to be aware of what the requested URL was**, no data is ever wasted, and no unnecessary CPU cycles need to be burned.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two Promise.all():
1. for all the request that don't need the results
2. for all the request that needs the results

Assume modules = [] is an array of modules that you want to execute with objects:

> ```
>     {
>         requiredResult: boolean;
>         url: string;
>     }
> ```

```
runCombination(modules = []){
    let needResultPromises = [];
    let backgroundPromises = [];

    modules.forEach((eachModule) => {
        if(eachModule.requiredResult){
            needResultPromises.push(RunModule(eachModule.url))
        }else{
            backgroundPromises.push(RunModule(eachModule.url))
        }
    })

    Promise.all(backgroundPromises);

    return Promise.all(needResultPromises);
}
```

So from the function above, you can see that some promise all is running in the background and the one with return will wait to the results.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure that answers my question. I want to create a scalable solution that does the least processing and async I/O possible across _any_ combination of modules. So in the example I gave above, running _any_ combination of those modules would only ever make **one** HTTP request during that entire run. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think the example you gave is making async requests that won't be used.

Comment: Check my edit to the original post for more clarification